# How to select a sub bookmark dynamically

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am having a word document in that i have given A as a bookmark for entire two pages and they are sub bookmarks in that main bookmark namely B,C,D.  How I can select sub bookmarks(B, C,D)dynamically.   I am using selection.Bookmarks(1)  to get the bookmark name but it is giving main bookmark instead of sub-Bookmarks.  Can anyone please help here.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54618667/edit) your question and add your code as as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You don't provide enough information *in the question* to understand what you have and how this should work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a sub-bookmark in Word. There are bookmarks. If you want to reference bookmark C, for example, reference it directly. Alternatively, if you're not concerned with a bookmark's name, you can reference it via it's Index number.

In your scenario, you could, for example, use code like:

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(1).Range.Bookmarks(2).Range
```

to reference the second bookmark that falls within the range spanned by the document's first bookmark. You might want to add error-checking to ensure that both bookmarks exist...

Note also there is generally no need to *select* a range - bookmarked or otherwise.